# Outline style is not getting applied when heading is used inside anchor

Tags: html, css

[image]When using heading inside anchor "outline-style" is not getting applied.
I added `outline: 4px dashed darkorange;` for `focus-visible` of parent anchor tag.

It works for auto style `outline: 4px auto darkorange;` , but for others like **solid, dashed, dotted** it's not working

Please let me know if I miss anything or if we have any workaround for this issue

```
<a class="focus-visible-only" href="#">Sample Link <a>
  
<h1 class="focus-visible-only"> Sample Heading </h1>
  
<a class="focus-visible-only" href="#">
  <h1> Heading inside Link </h1>
</a>

<a class="focus-visible-only" href="#">
  <span> span inside Link <span>
</a>
```

```
.focus-visible-only:focus-visible {
  outline: 4px dotted darkorange;
}
```

codepen link: https://codepen.io/vivid888/pen/xxYjNJx

Comment: @JaswinderKaur Could you pls check the codepen link, I use the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `<h1>` by itself is not an interactive element, you can't tab to it. To make it tabbable, apply `tabindex="0"`.

To make the nested `<h1>`-property take the `focus` styling, you need to use `a.focus-visible-only:focus-visible` to trigger the focus, and then afterwards use the selector `<h1>` to apply the styling.

I don't know why the `<h1> Heading inside Link </h1>`-element's behaviour is so weird - it wraps around the

```html
<a class="focus-visible-only" href="#">
  <span> span inside Link <span>
</a>
```

element for some reason. You could just apply `display: block` on the container `<a>`-element to change this.

Also, you can use `max-width: fit-content` if you don't want the link to take up the full width.

```css
.focus-visible-only:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px dotted darkorange;
}

a.focus-visible-only:focus-visible h1 {
  outline: 2px dotted darkorange;
}

a:last-of-type {
  display: block;
}

a,
h1,
span {
  max-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<a class="focus-visible-only" href="#">Sample Link <a>
  
<h1 class="focus-visible-only" tabindex="0"> Sample Heading </h1>
  
<a class="focus-visible-only" href="#">
  <h1>Heading inside Link </h1>
</a>

<a class="focus-visible-only" href="#">
  <span>span inside Link </span>
</a>
```