# Difference between inline-flex vs inline?

Tags: html, css

Regarding [Outline style is not getting applied when heading is used inside anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474426/outline-style-is-not-getting-applied-when-heading-is-used-inside-anchor/72474706)

Here in the above question, outline-style works for the heading inside the anchor only when the display is `inline-flex | inline-block | block`

I understand the difference between the following:

**inline-block**: Create a specific block for each element under its section to maintain the structure of each element.

**inline-flex**: Does not reserve any specific space in normal form.

But what is the difference between **inline** and **inline-flex**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content within `inline` will still display how you expect, but content within `inline-flex` will take on flex behaviour. So adding 2 `<div>`'s inside of an inline element will create 2 divs below each other, while adding 2 `<div>`'s inside of an inline-flex element they will display next to each other

```css
hr { margin: 3rem 0 }

.inline,
.inline-flex {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.inline > *,
.inline-flex > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}
.inline-flex{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is some text at the start the example divs
  &nbsp;
  <div class="inline">
    <div>Inline Child 1</div>
    <div>Inline Child 2</div>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  This is some text between the example divs
  &nbsp;
  <div class="inline-flex">
    <div>Inline Flex Child 1</div>
    <div>Inline Flex Child 1</div>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  This is the end of the text around the example divs
</div>
```